# How to override base adapter of socket using redis adaptor?

Tags: node.js, websocket, redis, socket.io

I am not able to find all rooms after clustering my node.js application using node-cluster ,i have used redis adaptor but it is also not giving the rooms of all instances, I need help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have to do this by creating rooms on redis server. I did n't found any solution except this.